# WPF ToggleSwitch: how to add Win 10 style

Tags: wpf, mahapps.metro, toggleswitch

I found this style [here](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/40186310-increase-win10-toggleswitch-default-margins) and add it into my `Window.Resources`:

```
<Style x:Key="Custom.ToggleSwitch.Win10"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource MahApps.Metro.Styles.ToggleSwitch.Win10}"
       TargetType="{x:Type Controls:ToggleSwitch}">
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0 0 10 0" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="ContentDirection" Value="RightToLeft">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10 0 0 0" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

The problem is that this line:

```
BasedOn="{StaticResource MahApps.Metro.Styles.ToggleSwitch.Win10}"
```

got error:

> Error 103 The resource "MahApps.Metro.Styles.ToggleSwitch.Win10" could
>   not be resolved.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Are you sure you have the latest version of Mahapps? [Direct link to source](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/develop/src/MahApps.Metro/MahApps.Metro/Styles/Controls.ToggleSwitch.xaml) at the bottom of the ResourceDictionary

Comment: What and where i need to copy this ?

Comment: Do you even have MahApps referenced in your Project?

Comment: You need to add the reference to use the libary: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7314433t(v=vs.90).aspx or use the nuget should also do the trick: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7314433t(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: yes i already have referenced in my project

Comment: Did you try my suggestion or what happened?

Answer (score 4):

Install MahApps using NuGet (Tools->NuGet Package Manager->Package Manager Console in Visual Studio): http://mahapps.com/guides/quick-start.html

And merge the `Styles/Controls.ToggleSwitch.xaml` resource dictionary into :

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.ToggleSwitch.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <Style x:Key="Custom.ToggleSwitch.Win10"
               BasedOn="{StaticResource MahApps.Metro.Styles.ToggleSwitch.Win10}"
                TargetType="{x:Type Controls:ToggleSwitch}">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0 0 10 0" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="ContentDirection" Value="RightToLeft">
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10 0 0 0" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use the style provided by MahApps, you would simply need to modify the ToggleSwitch to add the Style attribute as follows:

```
<Controls:ToggleSwitch Style="{StaticResource MahApps.Metro.Styles.ToggleSwitch.Win10}" />
```